# Unable to understand recursive factorial

Tags: java, recursion

I am new to recursive and I'm having trouble understanding how this recursive factorial function is calculated.

When I try to run through the code with my mind, this is how I visualize it:

> If number = 4,
>
> 1st return: 4 x 3
>
> 2nd return: 3 x 2
>
> 3rd return: 2 x 1

So in my mind it is (4 x 3) * (3 x 2) * (2 x 1) but obviously the right return would be 4 X 3 X 2 X 1 instead. I want to be able to understand how does it get 4 X 3 X 2 X 1.

```
 public static long factorial(long number) {
        if (number <= 1)
           return 1;
        else
        {
            System.out.println(number + " x " + (number-1) );
           return number * factorial(number - 1);
        }
     }
```

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answer by Jon should clear your doubt , Else try http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html (Debugger is used to identify code bugs , pretty advanced topic for beginners) but will help clear a lot of things of program flow,logic

Comment: You're visualizing the print line, rather than the return.  The return is a single int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your visualization should be:

> If number = 4,
>
> 1st return: 4 x (2nd return)
>
> 2nd return: 3 x (3rd return)
>
> 3rd return: 2 x (4th return)
>
> 4th return: 1

That then simplifies to 4 x 3 x 2 x 1, as expected.

Basically, you need to differentiate between "return value x" and "return the result of recursing, passing in value x".

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is that your print statement is a lie.  Change it to

```
System.out.println("factorial(" + number + ") = " + number + " x factorial(" + (number-1) + ")");
```

to see what's really happening. Then consider how your printed output resembles the mathematical definition that

```
     | n * (n-1)!     for n > 1
n! = | 
     | 1              for n == 0,1.
```

I've found that it helps to understand recursive functions as, well, functions. One big benefit of functions is that they encapsulate their calculations, hiding the specific details.  This leads to the "recursive leap of faith"—if you had a function that returned factorial(n-1), regardless of how it accomplishes it, it would be easy to use it to calculate factorial(n) based on the mathematical recurrence definition.  Trusting that the function will work makes it (almost) trivial to write the function!

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to understanding how factorials work is that the answer from the last iteration is the answer that gets returned.

Each iteration of factorial must wait for the following iterations before it has a value to return.

The actual operation that is performed is 1*2*3*4, not 4*3*2*1. Values are returned from last to first.